# Why does ansible throws error while encrypting the string?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ansible, ansible-2.x

When I run commands on my ansible 2.9 version on red hat 7 distro -

```
$ ansible-vault encrypt_string 'l3@TH!hFymu4b91!x[W!u[EL' 
New Vault password:  [ERROR]: User interrupted execution

$ ansible-vault encrypt_string '-w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m'
usage: ansible-vault [-h] [--version] [-v]
                     {create,decrypt,edit,view,encrypt,encrypt_string,rekey}
                     ...
ansible-vault: error: unrecognized arguments: -w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m
```

The first command succeeds while second one fails. Is it related to special characters. My program automatically generates passwords, so just one time escape won't help!

NB: The BaSh shell also would throw some errors, if you try to pass that string with a tilde using double quotes. But for single quotes, it won't complain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second command fails because the argument to `encrypt_string` looks like a command line option (because it starts with hyphen `-`). As with many command line tools, you can tell `ansible-vault` to stop looking for option arguments using the `--` marker, like this:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string -- '-w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m'
```

The entire process looks like this:

```
$ ansible-vault encrypt_string -- '-w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m'
New Vault password:
Confirm New Vault password:
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          38376339313764343364653131333536613738373863643230633761346331663837643664623237
          6138386635363661663562386430323061323831326534660a613837383263626336656332373464
          32306333303262653733626233383532373133663335343865373834653764313032333133663432
          6538306566373566610a353936663134326335373934643638333836643262363563333865366165
          63653736653733356261616431646538623736323139656531643137643234363237
Encryption successful
```

Comment: Could you share how to handle passwords containing asterisks (which also throws errors), hyphen like characters in Ansible inventory in an automated environment? Here's the question I asked related to asterisk issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105273/why-ansible-isnt-able-to-parse-asterisk-in-inventory-file

Comment: -- marker stops looking for arguments but doesn't process supplied input '-w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m'; it prompts to enter interactively. Is there any ways to avoid this?

Comment: If I run `ansible-vault encrypt_string -- '-w2kBT>ur=X{U`!43o&m'` it works just fine: it prompts me for a password -- which we expect, because we're not providing one -- and then emits the encrypted string.